# Fix a UIView(from storyboard) to the top of a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I've attached a UIView from the storyboard to the top of my UITableView and linked it to the code as IBOutlet, and I want it to be fixed to the top of my `tableView`. I've tried several ways:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    headView.center = CGPointMake(headView.center.x + scrollView.contentOffset.x, headView.center.y + scrollView.center.y);
    [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:headView];
}
```

and

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect newFrame = headView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = 0;

    [headView setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

and some other ways I found in the site, but none worked for me, I affraid because I connected `headView` from the storyboard.
How can I do it? many thanks!

Comment: What is going wrong? Provide images so that people can see the problem.

Comment: @RoboticCat The view just keeps scrolling with the table view like it did before

Comment: So you want the headView to be fixed at the top, no matter how table view scrolls?

Comment: Did you create your tableview programmatically? If not, then you can set tableview constraint and headerview constraint, make their vertical distance to be zero.

Comment: @gabbler I'm not using auto-layot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a UITableViewController and have added the view to the table views header view, hence it scrolls with the table.

If this is the case try changing your main view controller to a UIViewController and add the view and tableview there.